# Let iOS scroll source code properly

Tags: feature-request, ios

Currently on iOS devices source code snippets have a very poor scrolling behavior. Adding

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

to the corresponding container should fix that problem and add "momentum scrolling".

Comment: you can just use two finger scroll there

Comment: @JeffAtwood Might want to take a look at [example number one](http://www.uxbooth.com/blog/5-ios-behaviors-your-users-probably-don%E2%80%99t-know/).  This is sort of solved in iOS 6... sort of meaning code overflows into the next line.

Comment: It still doesn't have the "bouncy" feeling when scrolling with two fingers, you need the CSS for that. I couldn't see any overflow on iOS6, which I am using.

Comment: It overflows in mobile.  You must be talking about desktop.

Comment: So this would make scrolled source code bounce back when releasing one's fingers? (I'd not like that.) Or only when scrolling to far? (When scrolling past the total width/height?)

Comment: @Arjan: Only when scrolling too far, the rubber band effect. Also it has momentum, i.e. it doesn't stop scrolling the moment you lift your finger.

Comment: Then, me too! ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, you asked in July 2012, but a year earlier scrolling on mobile  was [changed to wrapping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98776/stack-exchange-mobile-launched/103249#103249), as *"Two-finger scrolling doesn't work reliably (or at all) on some of the Android devices I've tested with. Makes wrapping the only real option."* (Also, many users don't even know that their mobile might support two-finger scrolling.) Do you see scrolling of code blocks anywhere? Or is this about the "regular" website, not the mobile theme?