# Help the SO team create a css for a mobile site

Tags: discussion, mobile-web

Since Jeff & Co only ideas for mobile are to make the site Black & White and [statuscompleted the feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so), I propose that all we collaboratively develop a CSS skin so they can use it in m.stackoverlow.com

I will start with this:

```
#sidebar, 
.statscontainer,
#portalLink, 
#hlogo, 
#footer {display: none;}

#mainbar, #questions,
.question-summary,
.summary, 
#header, 
#content, 
#header #hmenus,
#question-header,
#question,
#answers,
#answers-header, .post-text
 {width: 100% !important}

#hsearch .textbox {width: 100px !important;}

body {margin: 0 5px !important;}
```

That make the site look like this:

[image]

Comment: Has there actually been any indication that they would use such a style?

Comment: Constantly horizontal scrolling has long been the most cumbersome thing about mobile SO.

Comment: @Michael: If the community supports the idea and they don't pay for it...  Seems foolish to not allow it...

Comment: @Michael ~ I haven't seen an explicit request for such a thing, but I do know that they are open to something given the previous requests. Save it for the chat-cast?

Comment: @drachenstern Ok, I was just curious if somebody had actually asked a dev. It'd be unfortunate to put a lot of work into it only to find out they're not actually interested in using the style at all

Comment: What's wrong with http://stackmobile.com ?

Comment: It's not a lot of work, the above CSS works for the most used pages. Some individual pages may have quirks. I'm trying to find a way to inject the css in my iPhone as I do with Stylish in Firefox. No luck so far.

Comment: @George: About Stackmobile: Where are my reputation? the replies? Can I vote? Can I answer a question? Can do a small comment? Why try to replicate a full site when you can make usable with a new CSS skin.

Comment: @Eduardo: It was just a thought - it's designed more for mobile devices than the current CSS.