# Mobile theme being incorrectly served to non-mobile browsers

Tags: bug, status-completed, internet-explorer

After installing IE9, I visited SuperUser's home page only to be greeted with:

[image]

Since I doubt that it's supposed to look like that, I'll assume it's a bug.

**Info:**

- OS: Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit
- Browser: Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: Just in case: it's the mobile look & feel. This is IE9 on a desktop/notebook right? (I've seen mobile CSS on a few occasions in other browsers too, but then a refresh fixed it, and at that time it seemed to be related to slow responding servers which was already reported by others.)

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, this is on a notebook.

Comment: (One nice detail in the mobile CSS: it makes the space in Super User very clear! ;-))

Comment: What does http://www.useragentstring.com/ tell you?

Comment: @Arjan I just wrote this comment ;) - is there a mobile version of SU?!

Comment: @studiohack: http://stackmobile.com/beta/superuser.com/stats

Comment: @studiohack, the mobile look & feel I was referring to is [the mobile CSS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/50689#50689), which uses the very same layout but some less graphics. (In the above screenshot you will see the purple "Super User" *text* rather than the logo, and things like that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in output caching, which has been fixed now.