# Mobile site being incorrectly served to non-mobile browser

Tags: bug, google-chrome, firefox, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sstatic.net “Malware” warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110690/sstatic-net-malware-warning)

This happened a couple of days ago. I couldn't find a way to switch back to normal site.
The question [Mobile theme being incorrectly served to non-mobile browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86362/mobile-theme-being-incorrectly-served-to-non-mobile-browsers) doesn't help.

How can I fix this?

- OS: Windows 7
- Browsers: Firefox 7, Chrome 15

[image]

**Edit:**

It doesn't look like mobile site. But I think SO thinks that it is.

[image]

Comment: This isn't the mobile theme - your browser isn't rendering the page correctly.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your caches?

Comment: I cleared the caches and delete cookies. Nothing help :(

Comment: @SimonSheehan see the second pic.

Comment: I'm having the same problem rendering the site - both the main SO site and chat.  Meta appears unaffected, though.  Happens in Safari 5.1, Firefox 7.0.1, and Chrome 15-ish.  Clearing cache and such doesn't appear to help.  Looks like when Chrome is trying to get the CSS for any of the sites, it's getting an error 403 back (also happens for the SO logo).

Comment: Alright, new comment because I know why I'm getting this now.  `sstatic.net` is being blocked by my university for supposedly having malware.  Not sure why it would be blocked, but at least I know what's going on on my end - not the first time I've seen them block something over nothing...

Comment: Exactly the same symptom as nil. Now I know where to knock. Thanks :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110690/sstatic-net-malware-warning

Comment: Yes that's what I think is going on also @balpha