# Stack Overflow MyOpenID Authentication failed

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is there an issue with the Stack Overflow MyOpenID authentication? I can't seem to log in with MyOpenID. I have checked with the MyOpenID authentication logs, and they do get the request which they authorise, but I still get an error stating

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.

I have had to create a new account which is really annoying as I have now lost what little reputation I had :-)

Comment: Is your global inbox working? This may be a bug from a few days ago.

Comment: I had the same issue around the time [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110690/sstatic-net-malware-warning) was reported, but now that I look at the resolution, I can't tell for sure whether it's the same bug.

Comment: For the record - the two accounts are http://stackoverflow.com/users/62338/gary-woodfine (old) and http://stackoverflow.com/users/847554/gary-woodfine (new)

Comment: I just tried again now and it still doesn't work.  To be honest this has been happening for over a month now. It's taken me till today to report it.

Comment: Gary, can you send your OpenID and any other details to `team@stackoverflow.com` so we can take a look?  MyOpenID has a few peculiarities around certain login formats, etc., with more info we can at least ascertain if it's a known issue and let you know what options there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered this bug.

`team@stackoverflow.com` helpfully offered me a merge account option.

As a last resort, I had a hunch:

My OpenID is of the form `http://firstname.secondname.myopenid.com`.

MyOpenID seems to do the same thing as Google does, and allows you to login with `http://firstnamesecondname.myopenid.com`. Stackoverflow could cope with this, so I'm back in business, with no merging necessary.

To avoid this in the future, I've added a login to my account which isn't MyOpenID.