# A Mobile App Specific to tags for SO

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mobile and iPhone optimized version of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-and-iphone-optimized-version-of-stack-overflow)

I was just wondering if it would be awesome to have an universal mobile app (native) supported by all mobile OS, specific to tags we are engaged in. It would be awesome to include features like:

- Subscribe or follow questions we like
- Subscribe or follow friends or people @ SO
- A notification feature included where we get updated of (likes, subscribes or follows)
- Chat rooms notifications

These are some that i could get off my brain, lol! please add if you have some. The  background of the whole idea is to keep engaged with Stack Overflow anywhere and everywhere, and also with the release of general API the community can get to get together in building up the idea. (BTW, i would love to contribute too.)

Comment: Chat is not in the API so that's a no. But I saw that API 2.0 spec has inbox read. So you can at least hopefully get the mentions but as of now I have not seen 2.0 beta yet.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) to see if this doesn't maybe exists already?

As for a universal solution, good luck to the developer that manages the source code of this, however there is already a huge amount of available software, and if there isn't one, feel free to start your own using the [API](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help).