# Preview on mobile page

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, markdown-preview

I suggest a preview on the mobile page. For questions, answers and edits to both, like on the desktop page.

I messed up formatting often enough to be annoyed that there is no preview on the mobile page and I'm surprised that noone suggested it before (at least I didn't find anything).

If it's too performance heavy to have a live preview update after every change in the text box, there could be a preview button next to the save button which leads to a page with only the preview, a back button and a save button (and the title bar and so on).

Comment: According to [Jeff's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-optimized-version-of-stack-overflow/12564#comment100659_12564) preview on mobile is suppressed consciously.

Comment: That could easily be solved with the preview button.

Comment: For me mobile-web is useless, I was mostly [looking for bugs there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911+%5Bmobile-web%5D). For everyday usage SE app (or even the full-web) is much better for modern mobile devices.

Comment: That may be true for you, but on my phone for some reason the app storage is separate from the rest of the internal storage and very limited, so if I install an app for everything that can as well run in a browser (Discord, Slack, Google+, YouTube, Stack Exchange, …), then I don't have any storage left. Also: I don't want to install an app for everything. Even if it doesn't run in background, requires no permissions and no storage, it's still one more icon in the list that I want to keep as well-arranged as possible.

Comment: The SE app is not compatible with all SE sites.The preview button or link would solve resource hungry live update issues.